# How to impersonate O365 room account

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, impersonation

I searched and couldn't find any way to impersonate an Exchange Online room account to get its calendar and events using EWS. Some results said that this account has been disabled for impersonation by default. So how to turn it on?

**UPDATE**: My solution is to create a new user account and in Exchange Admin Center, choose Admin Roles, add **ApplicationImpersonation** role and assign that new account to be its member. Or with power user, just use the Powershell command mentioned by @rojobo below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the MSDN Instructions on how to do so. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me! I set Role:ApplicationImpersonation for my 0365 admin account and it now can get room's and equipment's calendar :D